# Which tools for ASCII portfolio visualization?

Tags: ascii, finance, plotting

I. I want to do a simple graph from timestamp `YEAR-month-day` to `valuation`, not wanting to use spreadsheets. Is there some ASCII tool for it to see it on CLI? There are over 500k lines of data, and I want to see only a sketch of it like in Ascii:

```
Value
|          *
|    *   *   *
|  *   *       *   *
|*               *
|----------------------> Timestamp
```

II. Then, I want to see allocation like in pizza slices:

```
        - - -
     -\       -
   -    \ World -
  - Food \ Index -
   -    /  \   -
     - /oil \-
        - - -
```

I know how-to-get grappy CSV data in Python but totally inexperienced in visualization:

```
import csv
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';')
for row in csv_reader:
    # do something with row....
```

Before I do my own ASCII visualization thing, I want to know whether such thing exists. How do you visualize your portfolio in ASCII?

Comment: Perhaps related [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211097/historical-graph-to-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Searching here you will find that gnuplot (in dumb terminal mode) has been suggested before.