# Send a command from the console to a running X server

Tags: command-line, x11, console, remote

Is it possible to send a command from the console, say `tty1`, to the terminal currently occupied with X (in my case `tty7` as I use Debian), to tell for example `mplayer` to play a movie?

**Edit** - made a shorthand function with the commands I learned in the answer below:

```
function movie () {
  ORIG_TTY=`fgconsole`
  chvt 7
  DISPLAY=":0" mplayer -fs $1 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
  chvt $ORIG_TTY
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm exactly sure about what you are looking for. But to launch a new application inside a running X server you can use for example:

```
DISPLAY=":0" mplayer -fs video.ogg
```

You can choose the id of the X server, and you may add an optional screen identifier like `:0.1` to launch the application in screen number 1.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I looked for. Do you also happen to know how to incorporate the focus shift into that command (i.e., to emulate the Alt-F7 keypress to get the X display)? But your answer is correct.

Comment: Try with `chvt`. (It was hard to remember the name of this command, I don't use it everyday…)

Comment: Yes, `chvt 7` does it.